# PSCP using domain user

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, putty, scp

I use PSCP command line between two server but I have the following problem :

I have a windows box in a domain and how do I write the command line with domain user ?

`pscp.exe file.txt DomainUser@hostIP:"d:\folder"`

for example :-

user:- hi

domain:- welcome

hostIP:- 10.10.10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, as least not without an SSH server running on the remote server, which is not standard for Windows.

Edit: Please refer to the [CopSSH documentation](http://www.itefix.no/i2/faq/33). By default, domain users are not allowed to login via SSH.

Also, SFTP is not the same as SCP, so this might be an additional issue.

Comment: I install Copssh on windows server and i active SFTP service

Comment: I edited my answer for easier formatting instead of commenting. Please see the edit.